# Are there any other common names for what I've heard called a "Crossover Guitar"

Tags: guitar, terminology, acoustic-guitar, instruments, classical-guitar

That is to say, a nylon (or gut, I guess) guitar that has certain features usually associated with a steel stringed acoustic.  I'm talking about Spanish guitars with a thin neck, often with an acoustic's neck radius and profile, and sometimes a cutaway in the body.

Has anyone heard these called anything other than a "crossover" guitar?

Comment: Like this? http://www.zzounds.com/item--GODMULTENCORE?siid=134658&-xrG8SJADwH5c6ozcs_mYbRD2Dbj-hkEmM74IpZG5rjngcg7ARya-GMxoCk3nw_wcB=

Comment: It just seems to me to be classical guitars with a slim neck profile and a cutaway. Sometimes popular musicians want the effect of a nylon string and these guitars seem to cater to that crowd.

Comment: For me, I'm not a bad fingerpicker and I have real love affair with latin music.  Classical guitars don't suit my playing style all that well.  I can play them passably, and know a few bossa tunes, but honestly I just can't get used to that hunk of wood!  I know it's a sin, I just I can't let my thumb over the top shapes go and I want to take my nylon playing to the next level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no other term that I know of. The term "crossover" seems to be the term everybody uses, but sometimes they add "nylon-string" to make sure that people know they are not talking about guitars with steel strings.

I have written extensively about crossover guitars on my blog, circa 2009. My first blog entry is here: http://wheatwilliams.com/wordpress/which-guitar-to-buy-part-one/

For what it is worth, I have never owned one, but since I wrote these blog entries, the [Cordoba Guitar company has released their Fusion line](http://www.cordobaguitars.com/guitars/fusion). These look like well-designed crossover acoustic guitars at an affordable price.

Comment: I wonder how well something like one of the Fusion guitars would work with my tuning and playing style?  When I'm playing in a very small setting I like the acoustic sound of my Ovation with nylon strings, but it's really quiet; I'd expect an instrument that's designed to be played acoustically with nylon strings to work much better, but I'm not sure how much setup would be required to make something playable, and how confident I could be of liking the result.

Comment: I would say that the only way to find out would be to actually play one in a music store. And as for working with your tuning, that depends on the individual gauges of strings that you select, and on getting a good setup on the guitar.

Comment: Is there any good way to judge how a guitar is likely to feel/play once it is optimally set up, before undertaking the process?  Since optimal setup would likely require irreversible modifications to the nut and bridge, I would expect that returning the instrument if it proves unsatisfactory would require additional expense to set things back as they were.

Comment: thanks so much for this post, really informative.  I might post one or 2  questions in response to this in the next day or so